# Verifying a proof about convergent sequences converging to 0

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

The question goes as follows:

Let $X$ be the set of all sequences $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of real numbers such
that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n = 0$.

Use the definition of convergence to show that if $\{x_n\} \in X$, then there
is a $K \in N$ such that $|x_K| = \sup\{|x_n|: n\in N\}$ (i.e. $x_K$ is an element
of maximal absolute value).

Proof:

From the assumption about elements of X, we know that for $\{X_n\}\in X$ we have that for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can find an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. for all $n \geq N$ we have that $$|x_n|< \epsilon$$

This means that for all $k < N$ we have $$|x_k| \geq \epsilon > |x_n|$$

It therefore exist an $K\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $$X_K=max(\{x_1, x_2, ... , x_{N-1}\}) = \sup\{|x_n|: n\in N\}$$

$\square$

Any mistakes? If you see something I don't want the solution, just hints. If the idea is correct but proof not as good as it should be that would also be very helpful to know.

Comment: It is not quite right. You can not conclude the "$\ge$" in the second display. You should also *fix* an $\epsilon$. Perhaps, set $\epsilon=|x_M/2|$ for some $x_M\ne0$ (if there is no such $M$, all the terms are $0$). You can then argue as you first intended. (Choose $N>M$, if needed.)

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Makes sense. Thank you. @DavidMitra